# Grouping Flatlist items by date

Tags: javascript, react-native, group-by

I wonder how can I group the Flatlist items by their dates in React Native.

I mean, I'm trying to make something like Whatsapp's grouping system in the conversation screen.

On the chat screen, Whatsapp separates the messages with a date, but this separator is visible only in certain cases like, Messages from yesterday, messages from last week, last month, etc.

How can I make such a system any ideas?

Example:
[Here is a example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w12AA.png)

NOTE: I managed to do this in a different way, by getting item's date and with the index of item getting also previous item's date from the state, and checking with moment.js if the previous item's date is the same day with current item's date, then do not render anything, except this render the date component.

Im doing this check like so,

```
if (index > 0) {
            previousDate = moment(this.state.messages[index - 1].created_at).format(
                "L"
            );
        }
```

so what this does so far? its looking if the index is in the second item going to first item which is this.state.messages[index - 1] and getting its date...

its working like that but there is a problem, for example there are 2 messages from the same day as first 2 items in the flatlist,  its starting to check from the second item, becouse of index > 0,  if i do not add this control, its causing error becouse once its rendering the first item there is no item before this , `this.state.message[index -1]` gives error, and becouse of that its putting the date on top of the second item instead of first item.

I dont know how to figgure out this problem

Comment: Provide more info like what kind of response you are getting or have you tried something.

Comment: added a example screenshot

Comment: i added more information maybe someone can handle this thing :(

Comment: any solution so far?